# Erlang: How to install Erlang for Windows with specifying location

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq

I would like to install Erlang for Windows.
Erlang provides a Windows installer but the installer installs Erlang into fixed folder "Program Files".
I need to install Erlang into optional location.

Please let me know how to install Erlang for Windows with a path which I want to install.

Comment: uninstall and reinstall, the exe (windows binary) installer allows you to choose the target directory to install it.

Comment: Can I specify a location to install during installation wizard?

Comment: Yes, at it was always the case for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run the following command to specify a different installation location. Note that you should run the installer as an administrative user:

```
otp_win64_20.3.exe /S /D=C:\the\path\you\want
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @Luke Bakken for your answer. I was able to wrap this into my script and am copying this here in case someone finds it useful. I also borrowed from https://gist.github.com/chgeuer/8342314

```
Function Install-Erlang {
    Try{
        "Starting Erlang installation..."
        # Install Erlang
        # Update/review below path along with version of erlang being installed
        $args = "/S /D=C:\erl10.2"
        Start-Process -Wait otp_win64_21.2.exe -ArgumentList $args
    }
    Catch{
        Write-Error "Function Install-Prerequisites failed:" $_
        Exit 1
    }
    "Erlang installed successfully"
    #
    # Determine Erlang home path
    #
    $ERLANG_HOME = ((Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Ericsson\Erlang)[0] | Get-ItemProperty).'(default)'
    [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("ERLANG_HOME", $ERLANG_HOME, "Machine")

    #
    # Add Erlang to the path if needed
    #
    $system_path_elems = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", "Machine").Split(";")
    if (!$system_path_elems.Contains("%ERLANG_HOME%\bin") -and !$system_path_elems.Contains("$ERLANG_HOME\bin")) 
    {
        Write-Host "Adding erlang to path"
        $newpath = [System.String]::Join(";", $system_path_elems + "$ERLANG_HOME\bin")
        [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", $newpath, "Machine")
    }
}
```